# Problem with scaling histogram: "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) ..."

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

I am trying to scale my histogram with the factor of 0.1781628163, but I constantly get following error: "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Konference = pd.read_csv(r'Daiichianden.csv')
Konference.hist(column='1.915844504072473',bins=400,range=[0,8])

xlo=0 
xhi=8 
nbins=180 
data,bins = np.histogram(Konference['1.915844504072473'],bins=np.linspace(xlo,xhi,nbins))
KonferenceD = 0.1781628163*data
plt.title("Konference skaleret ift Daiichi")
plt.plot(bins,KonferenceD)




### Full error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0ce3aceeb8cd> in <module>
      6 KonferenceD = 0.1781628163*Konference
      7 plt.title("Konference skaleret ift Daiichi")
----> 8 plt.plot(bins,KonferenceD)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2793     return gca().plot(
   2794         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2795         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2796 
   2797 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1664         """
   1665         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1666         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1667         for line in lines:
   1668             self.add_line(line)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    390 
--> 391         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    392 
    393         if self.command == 'plot':

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    268         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    269             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 270                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (180,) and (179,)


----------


----------


### Converting the column into an array:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Konference = pd.read_csv(r'Daiichianden.csv')
a = np.loadtxt('Daiichianden.csv')
Konference.hist(column='1.915844504072473',bins=400,range=[0,8])

xlo=0 
xhi=8 
nbins=180 
Konference,bins = np.histogram(a['1.915844504072473'],bins=np.linspace(xlo,xhi,nbins))
KonferenceD = 0.1781628163*Konference
plt.title("Konference skaleret ift Daiichi")
plt.plot(bins,KonferenceD)



### Full error message
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-37dcc7e9580c> in <module>
      2 xhi=8
      3 nbins=180
----> 4 Konference,bins = np.histogram(a['1.915844504072473'],bins=np.linspace(xlo,xhi,nbins))
      5 KonferenceD = 0.1781628163*Konference
      6 plt.title("Konference skaleret ift Daiichi")

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Always share the full error message. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you have a column named `'1.915844504072473'`?

Comment: It was the value of the first cell, and since i have so much data, i just used that as the name of the column

Comment: Just edited my question so that you can se the full error message @AMC

Comment: The full error message that you added is different from the title.  You'll get better help if you are consistent.  `np.histogram` will be easier to use if you provide `numpy` arrays rather than pandas Series.  Convert the Series (column) to an array, and check its size and default.  If correct and logical, pass that to the function.

Comment: Did you read the article on [mcve]? What does your data look like?

Comment: @AMC I just rest the article and has tried to only include the necessary. My data is a dsv file with only one column, containing 72720 cells

Comment: _My data is a dsv file with only one column, containing 72720 cells_ That doesn't help us reproduce the error, though.

Comment: @hpaulj i just tried converting the column into an array, and inserted it in the function. The result and error mistake is presented in the bottom of the initial question

Comment: @AMC sorry, could you then specify what you mean when you ask what my data look like?

Comment: Thankyou for all your kind help. I just made it work somehow